# A deterministic and explicitly described walk which is like random ones

Tags: prime-numbers, random-walks

Consider a sequence $(X_i)_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ which every $X_i$ is $-1$, $0$ or $+1$ and lets define $Y_n = X_1+ \cdots + X_n$. We say the sequence $(X_i)_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ a Good Sequence if $Y_n \neq O( n^{\frac{1}{2} } )$ but for every positive real $\epsilon$, $Y_n = O( n^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon} )$.

My question:

- Do you know a good sequence which can be described with an explicit formula?

Notes:

- It's not so hard to create a good sequence but I mean, that I want one of them which can be described with an explicit formula (algebraic formula or ... ).
- A candidate is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). But the proof of that which $(\mu(n))_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is good is equivalent with Riemann-hypothesis.
- Almost surely every random walk (of usual ones) is a good sequence.
- (This note added after the first comment which solved the problem and I found which there are some solutions which are different from that which is in my mind and in this comment I've tried to draw the thing which I want a solution to be that) Mainly, I want a deterministic and explicitly described walk which is like random walks, and in other terms I want a deterministic and explicitly described walk which its graph is like the graph of random walks (The below image is from Wikipedia.org).

[image]

Comment: Would you consider $X_n=\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\ln(n+1)\rfloor-\lfloor \sqrt{n}\ln n\rceil$ (perhaps for $n>100$...) to be good enough? Or you need $Y_n$ also to oscillate?

Comment: Thanks, You've answered my stated question; But the thing which I had in my mind was a walk in which $Y_n$ oscillates like a random walk. Do you have any idea for this case?

Comment: Well, one may also multiply $\sqrt n\ln n$ by $\sin(\root3\of n$... I assume this is also not what was needed? After that, one may also add something which looks more randomly, but whose sums are much smaller, if you wish.

Comment: So, the real question is: May you tell ALL properties of random walks you wish to preserve? Otherwise it may long forever.

Comment: How about $X_n = \left( \lfloor 3^n \sqrt{2} \rfloor \bmod 3 \right) - 1$?

Comment: Why not use the outputof a deterministic random number generator as the function, whose output is then mapped to $\{-1,0,+1\}$ in the usual way?

Comment: The O() bounds are not enough to make the walk "Look random".  I think you want an additional constraint.  Something like "For any k, $X_i$ and $X_{i+k}$ are not asymptotically correlated."

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot prove anything, I strongly suspect that the fractional part of 
$e^i$
massaged to the right values has the properties you want. In other words:

$$X_i = \left\lfloor 3\left(e^i-\lfloor e^i \rfloor\right)\right\rfloor-1$$

Of course, there really no reason to use $e$ here, you could use $\pi$ or any other properly "random" number.